# What else I can do to optimise this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Scenario: Table with 1.5 - 2 million records

I need to execute a query that deletes old records, the only field being used in the condition is a date. I have already added an index to that field.

Problem: The query is taking too long (more than 14 minutes) to execute.

This is what I've done so far

```
mysql> create index idx_logs_log_date ON logs (log_date);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (9.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * from logs where log_date < "2013-09-11";
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys     | key  | key_len | ref  | row |Extra

+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------+------+---------+------+-----+-----

|  1 | SIMPLE      | logs  | ALL  | idx_logs_log_date | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1420480 | Using where |


1 row in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> delete from logs where log_date < "2013-09-11";

Query OK, 1163008 rows affected (14 min 20.87 sec)
```

I also tried deleting that index and adding a key to the field (which of course creates a new index), but there was no improvement in the response time.

So, my question, do you have any other idea about how to improve the response time?

EDIT:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(id) FROM logs WHERE log_date < "2013-09-14";
+-----------+
| COUNT(id) |
+-----------+
|   1182688 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.58 sec)
```

Comment: `SELECT count(*) from logs where log_date >= "2013-09-11";` ?

Comment: @Sebas 253736 rows in 0.11 sec.

Comment: Is log_date a DATE or a DATETIME?

Comment: In the future you should try and post questions like this on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). That's more for optimization and problems of a specific piece of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it's not the filter that's slow, but the deletion of the rows (test by measuring how long it takes to do a `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM logs WHERE log_date < "2013-09-14"`).

To speed that up you will need to tweak some server settings. But if you're simply keeping time based logs for the last X moments than you might want to look at date based partitioning so you can simply drop the table when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: I added the result to the question. 
I am actually deleting old data (older than 4 months) because I think this will be faster than having a partitioned tabled.

Comment: As it is with many of these things, testing is needed to be sure. It is most definitely a tradeoff, with partitioning deleting large amounts of data will be much faster (assuming you can drop the entire partition) and selecting will be faster if you only hit a single partition. But if you select from all partitions at the same time than you will have to choose between fast deletes or slightly faster selects.

Comment: but, if I take the partitions path then I guess that I will need to create the partitions dynamically, right? that is, at the end of each month a cron will create a partition with data older than 4 month, and also another partition with current data, then this cron will drop the partition with old data. Is that your idea?

Comment: I would recommend to create partitions per month and use a cronjob to create the next partition and drop the old partition monthly.

Answer (score 1):

since `SELECT count(*) from logs where log_date >= "2013-09-11";` returns 253736, and `SELECT * from logs where log_date < "2013-09-11";` returns 1163008, I deduct that the index is actually dropping the performances.

```
DROP INDEX `idx_logs_log_date` ON logs;
delete from logs where log_date < "2013-09-11";
create index idx_logs_log_date ON logs (log_date);
```

Comment: The reason I am adding the index is because this query will be executed monthly. Are you suggesting that the index is not necessary?. (I am not judging you, I'm just curious)

Comment: It depends. in this present case, no it is not. (it worsens the performances even). But then for your actual scenario, I don't know. How many months do you want to keep alive?

Comment: The table will keep data from the last 4 months. A cron will run this query at the end of every month. And of course, I have no idea how many records will be present in the table at the end of a given month, 2 million? 3 million?

Comment: ok, so you'd be deleting once a month, 1 month of a total of 5 months existing in the database. In this case the index would be useful.

Comment: check this link, i'm sure it will give you ideas: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_fastest_delete_from_large_table.htm

Comment: Interesting link, it's a shame it's for oracle databases and not mysql, however the ideas they expose can be translated to mysql. Anyways, thanks!